# Show or hide the border of a div - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, border

I have a multipart form to create a custom stamp. I have the main chunck of it working just fine, but am battling to get the border to take on the same colour of the text colour selection. I have a dropdown list for the border px and a dropdown list for the font color. The font colour works, i need the border to work and to take the same colour as the font color.
Can you let me know what i have done wrong here.

http://jsfiddle.net/ShauniD/ELER2/11/  (this is the full code, so you can see what i am trying to achieve.

I know there are better methods of doing this, but i am very new,and am learning piece for peice. So go easy if you will.

The Javascript is as follows:

```
function setColor()   {     
var color = document.getElementById("color").value;     
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = color;   
} 
function addContent(divName, content) {
 document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content;
}
 function border(border)    {
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderWidth = border;
}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
    <tr>

        <td>
            <input name="myContent1"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Add content" onClick="addContent('lineTwo', document.myForm.myContent1.value); setCookie('content', document.myForm.myContent1.value, 7);">
        </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
 <select id="color" onclick="setColor();">
        <option value="white">white</option>           
        <option value="black" selected="selected">black</option>           
        <option value="red">red</option>           
        <option value="lightblue">light blue</option>           
        <option value="darkblue">dark blue</option>           
        <option value="lightgreen">light green</option>           
        <option value="darkgreen">dark green</option>           
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>           
        <option value="orange">orange</option>           
        <option value="pink">pink</option>           
        <option value="purple">purple</option>           
        <option value="gray">gray</option>         
    </select></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>
    <select id="border"  onchange="border(this.value);">
        <option value="1px solid" selected="selected">1px</option>
        <option value="2px solid">2px</option>
        <option value="3px solid">3px</option>
        <option value="4px solid">4px</option>
        <option value="5px solid">5px</option>
    </select></td></tr>
</form>

<div id="myDiv">
        <div id="lineOne"></div>
        <div id="lineTwo"></div>
        <div id="lineThree"></div>
        <div id="lineFour"></div>
    </div>
```

Please have a look at the full code, so as to understand what it is exactly i am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of your function, for example to 'changeborder' and it will works for you.

The browser don't agree to use the same name as the element.

Comment: Or, simpler, remove or change the attribute `id="border"`. It’s not clear why using the same identifier is a problem here, but it is.

Comment: I have changed the function name as you suggested as well as removed the attribut (id="border"). I still cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Save your changes in your example. and I take a look there

Comment: You forget to change the name of the function in the onchange event.
And also change in the function the 'borderWidth' to 'border'

Comment: Thanks a mill. . .  stupid mistakes lead to big problems. . .  guess its a newbie thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: and [this is why all of that happened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238)

Comment: @Oleg Thank you for this wonderful explanation. It helps with the learning, and will get me on the right path to correct coding.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your option must be "0px none". Maybe "none" or "0px" are enough.