# checking if text is entered. Could not find error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to control if text is entered here is my code and it does not work i couldnt find whats wrong

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckInfos()
        {
            var x=document.forms("name").value;
            if(x==null)
            {
                alert("adınızı kontrol ediniz");
            }
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="button" value="test" onclick="CheckInfos()"/>
</body>
```

Comment: There should be a semicolon after the function in the onclick:

Comment: @Philip Bevan no it's not necessary

Comment: @FabienMénager sorry: i was clutching at straws. silly silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use "name" as an ID, but use getElementById.

```
var value = document.getElementById("foo").value;
```

But you should use a form :

```
<form name="myform" action="?" method="get" onsubmit="return CheckInfos(this)">
  <input type="text" name="foo" />
  <input type="submit" value="test"/>
</form>

<script>
function CheckInfos(form) {
  if (form.elements.foo.value == "") {
     alert("error");
  }

  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The reason why I discourage you to use IDs like "name" is because it may cause naming conflicts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id .

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var x=document.getElementById("name").value;
if (x == '') { alert('message'); } // instead of null thanks @minmin
```

Comment: it didnt work. I didnt use form element. Could it be a reason?

Comment: if (x == '') { alert('message'); }

Answer (score 0):

The form attribute is missing in your code that why it doesn't work

Comment: it worked without form attribute. Solution is--- if(x =="") ---