# Why the error comes like Function name is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I bind a function as a "click" handler for a button whose id and name are the same as the function's name. It gives an error that function is undefined and the function isn't run.

```
<input type="button" name="saveClientDetail" id="saveClientDetail" onclick="saveClientDetail();" value="Save"/>
```

The HTML containing this element is loaded using AJAX. The function `saveClientDetail();` is defined in an external JS file. When you click the button, it gives the error "saveClientDetail() is undefined". If I change the function name then it doesn't generate the error. Why is it so?

Comment: How is saveClientDetail() defined and is it included before you reference it in the input markup?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id

Comment: Maybe a name conflicting problem, because `id="saveClientDetail"` gives your button a unique identity in DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You have `id`,`name` , and also function with same '`saveClientDetail`' name. And the browser could not distinguish which one you meant by `saveClientDetail` name when you wrote that.