# Using the component ID as widgetVar name

Tags: jsf, primefaces, widget, variable-names

I have a simple question about component IDs and dialog (or other components) widget variable name.

Is there a problem of using the component ID as widget variable name of the same component?

E.g.

```
<p:dialog id="dlgRelConsultasRealizadas" widgetVar="dlgRelConsultasRealizadas" .../>
```

Comment: im asking if there is a problem doing it? i've see on some forum (i think is primefaces forum) that doing that is not correct, and i wanna know ur opinion about that.

Comment: Thanks for ur attention, i found and explanation here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579619/primefaces-3-component-id-and-widget-var-should-not-have-the-same-name). Moderator can close this post.

Comment: I guess you can post it as your answer so that others can benefit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This piece of JSF generates basically the following HTML (not exactly that, but in effects the same):

```
<body>
    <div id="dlgRelConsultasRealizadas">...</div> <!-- Component ID -->
    <script>var dlgRelConsultasRealizadas = ...;</script> <!-- Widget var -->
</body>
```

Interner Explorer has problems with this approach. [For some unclear reason](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/09/bug-162-global-namespace-pollution-in.html), it pollutes the global JavaScript namespace with variable references to all HTML elements by their ID (and name). So, basically, the `var dlgRelConsultasRealizadas` from the generated HTML output is after the rendering been overridden by the HTML element reference on the `<div>`. It's like as if the browser is afterwards doing the following in the global scope:

```
dlgRelConsultasRealizadas = document.getElementById("dlgRelConsultasRealizadas");
```

This will cause all original widget var functions to be completely unavailable because the variable `dlgRelConsultasRealizadas` is now referencing a [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement) instance which doesn't have the same functions as the original widget var like `show()`, etc.

Therefore, it's recommended to give the `widgetVar` an unique value which is not been used as ID or name of any (generated) HTML element. A common practice is to prefix (or suffix) the widget variable name with a consistent label. E.g. the `w_`.

```
<p:dialog id="dlgRelConsultasRealizadas" widgetVar="w_dlgRelConsultasRealizadas" .../>
```

---

**Update**: since PrimeFaces 4.0, for among others the above reason and also because "global namespace pollution" by "3rd party libraries" is considered bad practice in JavaScript world, widget variables are not anymore injected in the global scope. They are since PF4 only available via the `PF()` function.

In other words,

```
<p:xxx ... widgetVar="foo">
```

is now not available anymore as `foo`, but only as `PF('foo')`. See also Hatam Alimam's blog on the subject: [Intro to PrimeFaces widgetVar](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/).

Comment: Good explanantion, its better than my serachs. Thanks ^^

Comment: Chrome does that also AFAIK. As long as the id is withing naming container, everything will be OK, so it's a kind of forgotten landmine bug (it explodes once you've forgotten where you've placed it)

Comment: You're welcome. By default (with right doctype, decent JS code, etc), Chrome isn't that dumb as IE that it completely overrides the original variable if already definied before.