# p:dialog form submit loses action method after RequestContext update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a small form inside my `p:dialog`:

```
<p:dialog id="commentDialog" header="#{managedBean.dialogHeader}" widgetVar="commentDialog" modal="true" resizable="true" height="auto">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel for="comment" value="Comment:"/>

        <p:inputTextarea id="comment" title="Comment" 
                rows="6" cols="33"
                value="#{managedBean.comment}"
                required="true"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{managedBean.dialogFormSubmit}"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Can you tell why, when I hit the Submit button, the dialog does get closed but the `dialogFormSubmit()` in the `managed bean` does not get invoked?

I also tried changing to `p:commandButton` thinking the functionality required the `PrimeFaces` variant of the `h:commandButton` but got the same.

The question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381602/primefaces-dialog-commandbutton) and I tried to do the same but couldn't make it work and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958729/pcommandbutton-action-doesnt-work-inside-pdialog) which doesn't really seem to have a workable answer.

**UPDATE:**

The dialog was being shown from the managed bean but was also updated (the solution for which I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367277/1312080)) prior to showing by using the `RequestContext` API in order to refresh the header:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
context.update("commentDialog");
context.execute("PF('commentDialog').show();");
```

I have come to realize that this malfunction occurs only when I update the dialog (middle line above).  When I actually don't (which is not critical for the dialog functionality but the header appears blank), the submit action works fine.  So the context update seems to be what's messing it up and I don't know how to get both the update while retaining the submit functionality.  Could it be a bug in `RequestContext.update()`?

Comment: I've made a MCVE with your code and it works fine. I have a `p:commandButton` with a `actionListener` for calling your Java code (with `context.update`). This code updates the text header perfectly and show me the dialog. When I push over `Submit` button the `dialogFormSubmit` is invoked. If you want I can post my code in an answer.

Comment: As a side note the componentId and widgetVar should not have the same name

Comment: why is that, @EmilKaminski ?

Comment: Here is a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095787/using-the-component-id-as-widgetvar-name