# Add or Append text in p:textEditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces, text-editor

I have `p:textEditor` like the following

```
<p:textEditor 
                id="editor"
                widgetVar="editor"
                value="#{xxxController.editorText}" 
                height="300" 
                placeholder="Enter your content"
                toolbarVisible="false"/>
```

Have the following command button to add/append values to `p:textEditor`

```
<p:commandButton onclick="insertTag('[myValue]')" value="myValue" type="button" />

JavaScript
<script>
             
        function insertTag( t )
        {
            PF( 'editor' ).insertText( t ) ;
        }
        </script>
```

But i get `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'insertText' of undefined or null reference` when i try to click the `<p:commandButton`.

So how do we insert/append text using widgetVar or JavaScript to `p:textEditor`?

**Version details**

JSF 2.2,
PrimeFaces 6.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this...  Once you have the widget the "editor" variable is QuillJS object.

```js
PF('editor').editor.insertText(0, 'Hello', 'bold', true);
```

See: https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#inserttext

See: https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getlength

Comment: +1 this solved my issue but it always inserts the text at the beginning, how do we insert at the cursor? like if i type Hi and hit the button it should come like Hi Hello?

Comment: Yep read the docs for QuillJS its inserting at position 0.  I am sure with this example you can get clever and know how to find `length` and use that position to append.  My job was to get you working.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your valuable time, i got it working, just added editor.getLength()-1.

Answer (score 1):

See [Using the component ID as widgetVar name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095787/using-the-component-id-as-widgetvar-name)

> [...] This will cause all original widget var functions to be completely unavailable because the variable editor is now referencing a HTMLDivElement instance which doesn't have the same functions as the original widget var like show(), etc. [...]

(Append a `_vw` to every widgetvar name, to eliminate that issue)

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'insertText' of undefined or null reference

guess, that's exactly the cause, your code is not referencing the "editor"-widgetVar, but the "editor" html element, which does not know "insertText".

Comment: sure, will rename it like the way you suggested :) +1

Comment: @CodeNotFound beside that: `isWidgetVarExist(id)` looks strange to me... maybe remove that check for debugging.

Comment: Yes, it worked without that method, will remove it.

Comment: @dognose: this id widgetvar thing is not applicable anymore in recent versions afaik, they can be the same. The widgetvar is not stored in the document (or window) anymore

Comment: @Kukeltje okay, not sure what the most recent version is, and if OP is using that - so, i outlined that, cause it caused me headache years ago as well :)