# image onclick instead of button on click?

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I have a script that gets executed by an onclick, but it doesn't work when I use a image, only a button works. You can see the example at http://thomaswd.com/maze. Click on the "left" button then the down button, and they both work. But the right arrow doesn't work, for some reason. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Right button works but it's throwing JS error, `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: yea...I dont know how to fix it, I am an intermediate javascript coder

Comment: TypeError: right is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

right()

Comment: Strange, I don't understand why `right()` is not working but works if I rename the function to different name. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5b3Ez/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the id from 'right' to something else.  I am not entirely sure why this fails, but apparently within the html, since 'right' is the id, it hides the `right()` function.

In Chrome debugger, I changed the id to 'r' and the button works, although it is huge because of the css not matching anymore :)

As others noted, the 'up' and 'down' buttons work, and this is because their ids are 'top' and 'bottom'.

EDIT:

And here is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id), very strange issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Strange, I don't understand why `right()` is not working but works if I rename the function to different name.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5b3Ez/

Rename `right()` function to a different name and Hope that helps for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused as to why `right` doesn't work when `up` does under the same circumstance, but it seems that you can get it to work by binding via JavaScript (which you should really do anyway) instead of using `onclick`.

```
$("#right").on('click', right);
```

Comment: @user2034878 try wrapping that in `$(document).ready(function () {`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `right()`, just use `window.right()`.

In that context, I tried:

```
console.log(this.right===right, this.right===window.right, right===window.right);
```

and it displays `true false false`, but in case of other arrows, it is `false false true`. The explanation pointed to by Paul Hoenecke points towards the problem.