# Regular button and submit button in one form don't work

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a form returned back from a PHP request. The form has a submit button and a regular button. The submit seems to work just fine, but the regular one won't work! Please advise.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<tr id='actionRow' name='actionRow' hidden='hidden'>
    <td>
        <input class='actionBtn' type='submit' id='confirm' name='confirm' 
            value='Confirm' onclick='genChanged();'/> 
    </td>
    <td>                                
        <input class='actionBtn' type='button' id='cancel' name='cancel' 
            value='Cancel' onclick='cancel();' /> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

And here is the cancel() function:

```js
function cancel(){
        alert('in cancel');
        document.getElementById('editRow').hidden = false;
        document.getElementById('actionRow').hidden = true;
        window.location.replace("admin.php");
    };
```

The alert never appears!

Is it even right to put multiple non-submit buttons in one form?

**UPDATE**
my form looks something like:

```
<form action='save.php' method='POST' id='myForm'>
```

I've added the line ***`document.getElementById('myForm').submit();`*** to the *getChange();* function, to make the button be:

```
<input class='actionBtn' type='button' id='confirm' name='confirm' 
       value='Confirm' onclick='genChanged();'/>
```

Yet, *cancel();* function still doesn't work!

Comment: Take a look at this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms?rq=1

Comment: The thing is, i want to post data without using AJAX (it's an assignment), however, the submit button must submit the form with the method="POST", yet the cancel must hide some elements.

Comment: @rtimoshenko this example doesn't clarify how the submit action is handled. besides, cancel doesn't submit, which achieves what your _link_ says, but why doesn't it call the associated function with **onclick** event?

Comment: Just for fun, try this, see if this helps `<a href="javascript:cancel();">Cancel</a>`

Comment: Change onclick='cancel();' to onclick='cancel();return false;' to prevent the button from submitting the form.

Comment: @Fred the link works =D

Comment: @AndrewMcGivery did that, still nothing happens

Comment: @Roshdy Great, did it solve your problem?

Comment: @Fred no, i need to make it as <input type="button> or <button>, and i'm not using jQuery, so <a> won't give me that

Comment: @Roshdy Well, theoretically, your existing button should work. Re-check your syntax in your entire code. I'm sure you'll find something that's "out of whack".

Comment: OMG!!!!! The problem was the name of the function!!! i've changed it to cancelEdits() and it worked just fine!!!

Comment: @Roshdy Great! I should make it as an answer then.

Comment: @Fred yes, but what does the name has to do with anything? If you have an answer, I'll be glad to hear it =)

Comment: @Roshdy It's ok. My answer was basically to say that, "you need to check the name of your function", which happened to be just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same name for the id and the function name.

In my sample 'a' have the same id and function name test() and b have different id and function name cancel()... cancel work fine and test don't.

```
<script>
    function cancel(){
        alert('in cancel');
    };
    function test(){
        alert("in test")
    };
</script>

<body>
  <form action='save.php' method='POST' id='myForm'>
    <tr id='actionRow' name='actionRow' hidden='hidden'>
      <td>
        <input class='actionBtn' type='button' id='test' name='a' 
           value='a' onclick='test();'/>
      </td>
      <td>                                
        <input class='actionBtn' type='button' id='b' name='b' 
          value='b' onclick='cancel()' /> 
      </td>
   </tr> 
 </form>
</body>
```

For more informations you can see this helpful answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/1318727