# Strange javascript error: form field can't have same name as function?

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I just bumped into a very strange javascript error.

I have a form with a button input field:

```
<input type="button" id="flagAnswer" value="Flag" onclick="flagAnswer()">
```

In my js file that's included in the page I have defined the flagAnswer function:

```
function flagAnswer(){
   // do stuff
}
```

When I try clicking the flag button, however, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: flagAnswer is not a function
```

I've been fiddling around with this as it seems extremely straightforward, and the trouble seems to be that the id of the input field and the name of the function are identical. If I change the function name slightly, or if I change the input ID, it works.

Why is this happening? Any way to avoid it other than renaming one of them?

**Edit:**

jsfiddles to illustrate my point:

Original with error (click doesn't work) - http://jsfiddle.net/aQ9zt/1/

Changing function name (click works) - http://jsfiddle.net/r8m9L/4/

Changing input ID (click works) - http://jsfiddle.net/r8m9L/5/

Comment: flagTerminal? flagAnswer? Which is it?

Comment: @deceze - whoops, sorry, updated

Comment: function implementation _flagAnswer_ is bad syntax [no brackets]

Comment: @amdixon - can you elaborate?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: @amdixon - made jsfiddles, will update question

Comment: see this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id)

Comment: @amdixon - thanks! That seems to solve it... Guess this can be closed as a duplicate. (I've never ran into this error before as I mostly add click events using jQuery, which avoids this issue...)