# Why do an element's attributes appear in the scope of an inline function?

Tags: javascript, html

Given this code:

```
<button id="blah" onclick="alert(id)">Click me</button>
```

Clicking the button will alert "blah". Why does the `id` attribute become a variable visible  within the scope of the `onclick` handler?

Another example:

```
<button style="font-size:200%" onclick="console.log(style)">Click me</button>
```

Here we see that `style` refers to a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object, rather than the string value of the attribute. This is similar to what we'd get by referencing an index of the button element's `attributes` property, or through attribute properties like `this.style` (`getAttribute` would return the string value instead).

Where is this behavior specified?

http://jsfiddle.net/b8mpJ/

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder right answer too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's specified in Web Applications API. Quoting [whatWG's Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes):

> When the user agent is to get the current value of the event handler H, it must run these steps:
>
> [...] Using the script execution environment obtained above, create a function object with:
>
> [...] **Lexical Environment Scope**
>
> - Let Scope be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(document, the global environment).
> - If form owner is not null, let Scope be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(>form owner, Scope).
> - If element is not null, let Scope be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(element, Scope).

NewObjectEnvironment() is defined in ECMAScript edition 5 [section 10.2.2.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.2.3). You may probably know its effect better from [with](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.10) statement (where it's used as well). In other words, the target element's properties are checked as well when looking for a particular name binding in the event handler's function.

Comment: I think you nailed it. Might be good to quote ES5 section 10.2.2.3 here for anyone else who comes across this; steps 2 and 3 are vital to understanding why this happens. Thanks.

Comment: Minor nit-pick, but given that whatWG reflects what browsers actually do, saying the behaviour is *because* of whatWG is probably backwards (for now): whatWG is just documenting what browsers do in an attempt to standardise behaviour. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, do you happen to know if this behavior has "always" existed? Somehow I've never noticed it before today.

Comment: @DaggNabbit Haven't found any reference for 'always', but [this article](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/12/scoping-with-html-and-inline-event-attributes) describing the same problem is quite (2010) old. )

Comment: @raina77ow, interesting article, thanks. Hearing that it took old PointedEars any amount of time to work this out makes me feel not quite so dumb for being stumped by it. ;)

Comment: @DaggNabbit—no idea when it came into being, but I suspect very early (a "DOM 0" thing). I've never seen anyone rely on this behaviour, it surprises me that it's been "standardised" as it seems like a bad idea, like making IDs and NAMEs global variables (which, though implemented in every browser to be compatible with ancient IE, has not been similarly "standardised" as far as I know).

Comment: @DaggNabbit—it seems to have been there from the very beginning: [stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/855543](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/855543).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where it is specified, but what's happening is that your handler is being called with the `this` variable set to the element. That's why the attributes are visible, since `id` could be seen as a shorthand form of `this.id`.

Comment: Variable resolution on the scope chain does not involve *this*.