# How do i clear a canvas?

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

By some starnge reason it does not work for me to do the

```
canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

here is my code:

```
function startDraw(){
document.getElementById('PaintArea').setAttribute('onmousemove', 'getMouse(event)');
}
function stopDraw(){
document.getElementById('PaintArea').setAttribute('onmousemove', '');
}
function Paint(){
var Size = document.getElementById('Size').value;
var Opacity = document.getElementById('opa').value;
var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
canvas = document.getElementById('PaintArea');
if(canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.globalAlpha = Opacity;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(musX-10, musY-10, Size, 0, Math.PI*2); 
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
}

function clear(){       
canvas.width = canvas.width;
}

function getMouse(event) {
musY = event.clientY;
musX = event.clientX;
Paint();
}
```

button:

```
<button onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
```

in the chrome console it says : "document.clear() is deprecated. This method doesn't do anything."

i also have these global varables:

```
var musX;
var musY;
var canvas;
```

Comment: Same reason and solution as I explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/855543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing based on the error message... try this:

```
<button onclick="window.clear();">Clear</button>
```

If that works, consider using a less vague function name, something like `clearCanvas()`

Comment: `window` is a host-defined property.  It should not be used to access the ECMAScript global object. Instead, use `var global = this;` in global context (the variable identifier does not matter), and then `global.clear()`. Likewise, `global.clearCanvas()`. See my comment to the question for details.

Comment: And what if the next browser provides a `window.clearCanvas` property? Error-prone, not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <button onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
> ```
>
> in the chrome console it says: "document.clear() is deprecated. This method doesn't do anything."

You have run into the [legacy scope chain augmentation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/855543).

In this case, `clear` is the name of a property of the object referred to by the host-defined `document` property, which is in the scope chain of the code in the event-handler attribute value.  In order to access your functions *reliably* (cross-browser), you need to circumvent the scope chain.

Possible solutions:

2. Make your functions methods of your own object:

   ```
   var myObject = {
     startDraw: function (…) {
       // …
     },

     // …

     clear: function (…) {
       // …
     }
   };

   …

   <button onclick="myObject.clear()">Clear</button>
   ```
3. Access the global object, whose methods your functions are, directly:

   ```
   var _global = this;

   // …

   function clear ()
   {
     // …
   }

   …

   <button onclick="_global.clear()">Clear</button>
   ```

   (You may choose any other variable identifier in place of `_global` as long as it does not collide with a built-in or host defined symbol.  `_global` is an identifier unlikely to collide.)

Approach 1 is recommended as it reduces the number of user-defined global symbols, thus the likelihood of collision with built-in and host-defined symbols.