# With input boxes type=checkbox - onclick function naming

Tags: javascript, html

In both chrome and IE, this code fails:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var state = false;
    function jsClicked(){
        state = !state;
        console.log("Clicked " + state);
    }
</script>

<input id="jsClicked" name="jsClicked" type="checkbox" onclick="jsClicked()">
</input>
```

but changing the name of the onclick function resolves the issue. The error being thrown is:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Here's the fiddle: [onclick error fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwc4E/4/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id

Comment: I don't know why but it seems that it's confusing the element id with the function name.

Comment: Off topic, but I'd be curious to know why you need the `state` variable when the input itself has a `.checked` property that you can read.

Comment: Im in ie 8, no jquery. thanks for the link, ie reserving the name makes sense

Comment: @roguequery just give your checkbox a different ID from function name

Comment: try adding text to the script tag <script type="text/javascript">. I tried it out in chrome and it worked.

Comment: No one mentioned jQuery. If you were referring to my comment, I'm talking about the native API. And it doesn't reserve the name. It's that the name appears automatically in the variable scope, so it shadows the global variable with the same name.