# Multiple var textboxes for javascript

Tags: javascript

I have html textboxes, but for somme reason when I hit submit it doesn't show both neither of the 3

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function readBox() {
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;         
        alert("You typed " + email, + age, + tShirt);
    }
</script>
```

any ideas why this isn't working?

```
<form name="readBox" action="/">                        

    <label>Age:</label>                     
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age">

    <label>T-Shirt Size:</label>                        
    <input type="text" id="tShirt" name="tShirt">


    <label>Email Address:</label>                       
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

    <br />              
        <input type="submit" style="display: inline-block;" onClick="readBox()">
```

Comment: Without your HTML, absolutely no idea :)  Please include all relevant source code.

Comment: The answer that got deleted is probably correct - are you getting an error or is it just not working?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using jQuery?

Comment: @swaggyK where is your textbox with ID phone.....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are only getting value of `"You typed " + email`

```
alert("You typed " + email + age + tShirt);
```

You had many commas. Also, you don't have any element with ID `phone`, and `tShirt` variable is not defined.

Comment: Your answer doesn't tell the poster what the correct syntax should be :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't go to the function readBox only. Your form name and function name to be executed onclick are same. That's why it's creating problem.

Change your form name and it should go to that function.

Here I have something which worked for me:-
HTML

```
<form action="/">   
                <label>Age:</label>                     
                <input type="text" id="age" name="age">

                <label>T-Shirt Size:</label>                        
                <input type="text" id="tShirt" name="tShirt">


                <label>Email Address:</label>                       
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

                <br />              
                <input type="submit" style="display: inline-block;" onclick="readBox()">
              </form>
```

Javascript

```
function readBox() {
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;         
        alert("You typed " + email +" "+ age);
    }
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id) is a question about conflict between form or it's element's name & function to execute.

Answer (score 0):

1. you must remove comma in alert.
2. remove action in form
3. change function name of script

   ```
   function read(){
   var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
   var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
   var tShirt = document.getElementById('tShirt').value;       

   alert("You typed " + email +","+ age+"," + tShirt);

   }
   ```

`

```
<form name="readBox"> 
    <label>Age:</label>                     
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
    <label>T-Shirt Size:</label>                        
    <input type="text" id="tShirt" name="tShirt">
    <label>Email Address:</label>                       
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

    <br />              
    <input type="button" style="display: inline-block;" onClick="read()" value="submit">
```