# Firing JS function from onkeyup event input

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

I have this very basic code that I feel should be working but isn't.

I have this form:

```
<form id="search-box" action="">
     <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search here.." onkeyup="search(this.value)"><!--
   --><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

This form fires a JS search function. This search function contains:

```
function search(input){
    alert(input);
}
```

I have linked the JS file containing the function in the head of the html document:

```
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
```

But the problem is this isn't working. I'm getting an error when the onkeyup is fired:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function    localhost:16:201
onkeyup localhost:16:201
```

May I get some assitance?

Comment: Can you provide the full html and js code ?

Comment: The `object is not a function` message is a good clue.  The name `search` does exist in the right scope, but it's not a function.  You might try opening the JS console on the page and logging out the value  of `search` to see what it is.

Comment: @LibertPiouPiou http://jsfiddle.net/WpvY9/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have a function named `search` and an element with the `id` of `search`. HTML elements with `id`'s become global variables by that name, so the element with the `id` of `search` overwrites the `search` variable that was your function.

Try something like this.

**HTML**

```
form id="search-box" action="">
     <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search here.." onkeyup="doSearch(this.value)"><!--
   --><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function doSearch(input){
    alert(input);
}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, I've never known that. Has solved my problem, will mark as correct answer once the timer is up!

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you can't have an element ID and function names same in a form. These creates conflicts.

When you add a ID in your form it adds that element as form[id]. So if you will have the same names of functions they will create conflict in same form.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id) is a very nice question has been answered about same.