# Uncaught TypeError: info1 is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to loop through the value entered from 'Info1" and displaying range sliders.

Ex: Info1 is 10, then would like to add 10 range sliders. I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: info1 is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup"

Could anyone help me. Thanks in Advance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function info1()
{
  var num1 = document.getElementById("info1").value;  
  if (num1 == '')
      num1 = '0'; 
  alert(num1);
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php $x=1; $num1 = 0;?>

<form method ="post" action ="info.php" >

 <table>
  <tr> <th> numeric A: </th> 
  <td> <input type="text" name="info1" id="info1" onkeyup="info1()" value=""> </td> 
  </tr>
  
 <?php 
while($x <= $num1) { ?>
 <tr> <th> sliders</th>
 <td><input type="Range" name="slider" min="0" max="1000" step="100" value="0"></input></td>
   <?php $x++; } ?>

<tr> <td> </td> 
 <td> <input type ="submit" name="insert" value ="Add"> 
 </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Choose a function name that is different from the ID, or use standard [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firing JS function from onkeyup event input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588547/firing-js-function-from-onkeyup-event-input)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes, I changed the function name to info_1... i get alert with the info1 value correctly. But range sliders are not getting added. It doesn't trigger. Is any way to trigger to add range sliders.

Comment: You need the `change` event for this.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers take the ids of elements and make them into global variables, so your function `info1` is replaced by your info1 element. Change either the name of the function or the id of the element.