# Beginner Javascript - Object is not a function

Tags: javascript

Hey guys taking a stab at my first `Javascrip`t validation but getting stuck pretty early on. I am calling a `JS` function from `onkeyup=""` but I receive the error:

```
Object is not a function
```

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3> My Sign Up Form</h3>
        <form name="signup">
            <label>First Name<input type="text" name="fname" onkeyup="fname()"/></label><div id="fnameVal"></div><br>
            <label>Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" onkeyup="fourchars();"/></label><div id="lnameVal"></div><br>
            <!--<label>Email<input type="text" name="email"/></label><div id="email"></div><br>
            <label>Password<input type="password" name="password"/><div id="password"></div></label><br>
            <label>ConfirmPassword<input type="password" name="confirmpassword"/><div id="confirmpassword"></div></label><br>-->
            <label><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></label> 
         </form>
    </body>
    <script>    
        function fname(){
            alert('jjjj');
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: try wrapping your javascript code in document ready ?

Comment: You might think about putting your JavaScript before the `</body>` rather than the `</html>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id

Answer (score 1):

you can't have your function name same as your control name. i.e. fname & fname()

```
            <label>First Name<input type="text" name="fname" onkeyup="validateFname()"/></label><div id="fname"></div>
```

OK, Try something like this.

Comment: +1, you are right. But it seems to be a comment. Add some more explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace your onkeyup to this. I know it is the same code but sometimes it works when you relace you code by the same code form an other site. BTW it works fine if I test is on a site.

```
onkeyup="fname()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Raname your function to be different from the input name.

e.g.

```
<script>
    function valname(){
      alert('jjjj');
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3> My Sign Up Form</h3>
    <form name="signup">

    <label>First Name<input type="text" name="fname" onkeyup="valname()"/></label><div id="fnameVal"></div><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as `fname` is a reference to your element in your form. Try changing the name of the function or the name of element.

```
function fnameFunc() {
   alert('jjjj');
}
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="text" name="fname" onkeyup="fnameFunc()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery on keyup

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('body').on("keyup", "input[name=fname]", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    // do your stuff
});


});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/farshadajdar/L7cokv32/4/)