# Failure to calculate the total monthly payment for a car loan. What's going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, superscript

Updated code. calculate() still not working. The monthly payment amount is ultimately not being passed to the "total" id box. Does anyone see what the underlying problem is here? My syntax seems to be correct, I believe there may be a problem with my specification of where each variable is applied in the code.

I am having problems getting the function calculate() to pass the correct result in "total." Any possible solutions? The action of clicking the calculate button should display the total, but is displaying nothing at all, as if the button does not activate the calculate function at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
var P = document.getElementById("price").value;
var D = document.getElementById("DP").value;
var R = document.getElementById("R").value;
var N = document.getElementById("N").value;
var i = (R / 1200);
var n = (N * 12);
var m = ((P - D) * i * Math.pow(1 + i,n)) / (Math.pow(1 + i,n) - 1);
var result = document.getElementById('total');
    result.value = m;}
</script>
</head>
<div align="center">
    <hr>
    <form name id="Main">
        <input type="number" id="price" placeholder="Price of the Car"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="DP" placeholder="Down Payment"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="R" placeholder="Annual % Rate"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="N" placeholder="# of Years Loaned"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="javascript:calculate();"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="total" placeholder="Total Cost..." readonly=""/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
    <hr>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought `<br` is deprecated

Comment: No, it's not. But it is not intended for view layout, just to break a line of text. Many people still use it, and it's ok for a quick test or something like that, but for layout you should use css properties, div positioning, etc. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: @user9018 The question has been edited to contain correct code, it won't help anybody else with the same problem. Please consider editing the question so that the answers matches your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
    var P = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var D = document.getElementById("DP").value;
    var R = document.getElementById("R").value;
    var N = document.getElementById("N").value;
    var i = (R / 1200);
    var n = (N * 12);
    var m = ((P - D) * i * Math.pow(1 + i,n)) / (Math.pow(1 + i,n) - 1);
    var result = document.getElementById('total');
        result.value = m;}
</script>
</head>
<div align="center">
<hr/>
<form id="Main">
    <input type="number" id="price" placeholder="Price of the Car" />
    <br />
    <br/>
    <input type="number" id="DP" placeholder="Down Payment" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="number" id="R" placeholder="Annual % Rate" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="number" id="N" placeholder="# of Years Loaned" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Monthly Payment" onclick="calculate();" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Total Monthly Payment:<input type="number" id="total" placeholder="Total Cost..." readonly="" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
<hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Math.pow()` function instead. The ^ operator is not for mathematical power operations (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

Also, It's `result.value = m`, not the other way around :)

Also 2: `R` and `M` seem undefined to me, you have to initialize those variables with something, like you did with `P` and `D`.

Also 3: use chrome dev tools or anything like that. It will make your life much easier. Remember, javascript doesn't mean "no IDE" :D

Comment: How would I apply this to a variable, say n?

Comment: No problem, just Math.pow(123, n) for example. You can use n as an argument for any function call, including pow. Have in mind that this is functional programming so 2^3 becomes Math.pow(2,3). See?

Comment: Starting to understand, I've never come across superscripts before in a function. So in this case of var m = ((P - D) * i * (1 + i)^n) / ((1 + i)^n - 1); ... how would Math.pow (x,n) be utilized to produce the correct function?

Comment: substitute `(1 + i)^n` with `Math.pow((1 + i), n)`

Comment: For example, replace (1+i)^n with Math.pow(1+i, n). However, this is a general thing, it's not superscript specific or anything. Imagine if it were something like Math.add(a,b) instead of a + b. It's a function call instead an operator, nothing more. Not all operators exist in all languages, so in this case, while you can use + to add, you must use the pow() function to raise a number to a power.

Comment: Okay thank you, that has been applied. Now just need to solve the problem with the total not being calculated.

Comment: Can you update your answer and also indicate which error or behavior are you getting? Also, glad it helped, but more importantly, did you understand why?

Comment: Yes! That helped me immensely, I thank you again. Now I will be able to use Math.pow() correctly in the future. Now to getting this function to work correctly. Basically, I am not getting a total to display upon clicking the id "calculate" button.

Comment: It's result.value = m, not the other way around!

Comment: Fixed. Still trying to get the total to display.

Comment: Try degugging it. For example I would divide the problem into smaller problems. I would hardcode a value to m (let's say... 42), and see if that displays. If that works, then you have a problem in the calculations part. If it doesn't, then it's a js/html problem.

Comment: Still no result, even with a hardcoded value assigned to m. I am stumped here! it must be something simple I am overlooking

Comment: I edited my answer with more info, I believe you havent initialized R and N properly, before trying to use them to calculate n and i. (Or are you doing that someplace else?)

Comment: Also, use the developer tools in chrome for example, and have a look at the javascript console, it will indicate you if something is exploding before reaching the line that sets the value.

Comment: The ^ operator DOES exist in javascript, but it's something entirely different: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR

Comment: Completely correct @y34h, I meant the "power" operator does not exist. Hence the unexpected results :P. I'll update my answer, good point.

Comment: How would you define these variables? There may be some confusion from my IDs and my variable names, this may be causing the function to not run properly. M is the total, would I need to define it as var M = main.M.value; ? Also, @y34h how would I use that operator in my m variable?

Comment: R is not being initialized. You have to do something like R = Main.R.value. Binding of your input fields and your JS variables does not happen automatically. It's the same you did with P.

Comment: See vitr's answer. The user fixed your entire code for you.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, your original code will never work, as it has too many errors.
Here is the corrected fiddle for you, please, have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/q330fqw8/

```
function calculate() {
  var P = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var D = document.getElementById("DP").value;
  var R = document.getElementById("R").value;
  var N = document.getElementById("N").value;
  var i = (R / 1200);
  var n = (N * 12);
  var m = ((P - D) * i * Math.pow(1 + i,n)) / (Math.pow(1 + i,n) - 1);
  var result = document.getElementById('total');
  result.value = m;
}
```

I removed `id="calculate"` in HTML, because of this: [Why JS function name conflicts with element ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id)
In Javascript, the 4 variables `P`,`D`,`R`,`N` should be set properly. Finally, this `m.value = result;` -> `result.value = m;`
but I guess, you've already corrected some errors in the question. I worked with your original code.

Comment: I think it would be more educational to the poster if you enumerate all the corrections you did to the code, than just saying "it has too many errors". I upvoted your answer however.

Comment: @vitr You are a saint, thank you! Curious though, what were the critical errors that were preventing the result to display? I would like to know in order to self educate. Thank you again, by the way.

Comment: totally agree, hopefully he will go through line by line, as everything there is pretty basic stuff

Comment: New html programmer here. It was pretty simple, it has been a long day and I was totally perplexed!

Comment: Glad you finally got it to work! But please take the advice on using developer tools and google some javascript debugging techniques and such, it will help you a great deal :)

Comment: @user9018 please re-edit you question to add both your original code and the corrected version, so it is useful to other users.

Comment: Aptana Studio 3 uses Mozilla Firefox for the browser. I will start researching how to use their debugger.

Comment: Updated the answer, @user9018 , please, don't be overwhelmed, we all do same mistakes all the time.