# onchange mistake (function and name)

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

Just because name and onchange function are the same in the select is doesn't work.
So, it's normal that the first select doesn't work ? (https://jsfiddle.net/ay1fvruz/)

```js
function selectTypeParty(value) {
 alert(value);
}
function test(value) {
 alert(value);
}
```

```html
don't work <br>
<form id="mainForm">
    <select name="selectTypeParty" onchange="selectTypeParty(this.value)">
        <option value="melee">Melee</option>
        <option value="classic">Classic</option>
    </select>
</form><br>
work <br>
<form id="mainForm2">
    <select name="selectTypeParty" onchange="test(this.value)">
        <option value="melee">Melee</option>
        <option value="classic">Classic</option>
    </select>
</form><br>
work <br>
<form id="mainForm3">
    <select name="test" onchange="selectTypeParty(this.value)">
        <option value="melee">Melee</option>
        <option value="classic">Classic</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This answer may be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/3052648

Answer (score 0):

You can go around the simple html limitation by using a jquery, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ay1fvruz/1/):

```
$(function () {
    $('select').on('change', function(){
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but he is good, mainForm2 and mainForm3 work, it,s just i don't understand or that it's normal that the mainForm1 don't work.