# Pass a JavaScript function as parameter within an onclick attribute

Tags: javascript

EDIT: This turned out to be an odd problem that I have no idea what is going on. How can this HTML

```
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                Find:
                <textarea id="replace" rows="5" cols="1">to replace</textarea>
            </div>
```

Make this code fail?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function go(transform_function) {
            alert('go');
            transform_function('test');
        }

        function replace(output) {
            alert('rep');
        }
    </script>
```

Replace

Fiddles of the oddness

Fails
http://jsfiddle.net/0zhwxcsL/

Works
http://jsfiddle.net/0zhwxcsL/1/

Comment: working fine, what´s the question? http://jsfiddle.net/jqvsf2c3/

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/k90t1128/ (provided the JS is in the head/before that onclick in the body)

Comment: Why not just call that function in `addContact`? You can pass id as a parameter to the `addContact` which you will then pass to `refreshContactList`

Comment: Did you try this before asking? Always try your code before asking.

Comment: son of a... I named my function go, I was using sample code, to make a clearer question

Comment: I guess one cannot make function go() and have this work? Should I just delete this question?

Comment: This is where I failed... Updated question, but not sure whether it's worth keeping around. http://jsfiddle.net/k90t1128/1/

Comment: Hmm that works too...

Comment: @Maverick: because then you can have a second link: `<button onclick="go(2, somethingElse);">Another</button>`, without changing `addContact`.

Comment: Ok, so I have no idea what is going on here, can anyone explain it, I've finally isolated the problem to two separate fiddles, and I don't understand why HTML is impacting the whole situation. Sorry that the sample I tried to provide earlier wasn't a clear representation of my problem. Fails
http://jsfiddle.net/0zhwxcsL/
Works
http://jsfiddle.net/0zhwxcsL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Javascript Functions are just objects and like any other object you can pass a function as a parameter within a function. This is a very normal and heavily used practice.

```
<button onclick="addContact('1', refreshContactList);">Go</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function addContact(id, callback) {
    console.log(id);
    callback();
    // You can also pass arguments if you need to
    // refreshCallback(id);
  };

  function refreshContactList() {
    console.log('Callback Achieved');
  };
</script>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/krtpby04/)

**Updated Answer**

The problem is you have a form element id using the same name as the function you want to call and it's causing a reference conflict on the page. Add something like ID to the end of your form element ids to remove the conflict or change your function name into something more descriptive like replacer.

[Reference JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v1kxess/2/)

A more detailed answer to what is going on can be found at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id) other stack overflow question.

Comment: thank you for the answer, my problem turned out to be something quite different, I've edited the question to reflect the real problem

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed update and pointing me to the other question. I was wondering what the issue was.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there.. Hence why stackoverflow is so awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This works because you are storing the string from the `refreshContactList` button into a variable named `refreshCallback`. The `refreshCallback()` function that is being called is made behind the scenes to `refreshContactList()`. That said, this is too complicated!

Refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtL1780z/1/). Call the `addContact()` function, passing the `id` from that function. Then call the `refreshContactList()` function, passing the `id`. The `refreshCallBack()` function isn't needed.

Comment: thank you for the answer, my problem turned out to be something quite different, I've edited the question to reflect the real problem