# My javascript won't run, Is the file not linked correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to this and I can't figure out whats wrong with my school project.  I think maybe my javascript file isn't linked correctly, or maybe the code is just broken?

```js
// }
// Commented out above "}" - Edits must be at least 6 characters
 function repost() { 
       var epost = document.getElementById('epost');
       var repost = document.getElementById('repost');

       if (epost.value != repost.value) { 
           repost.setCustomValidity('Epost adresserna måste matcha.'); 
       } else { 
           // input is valid -- reset the error message 
           repost.setCustomValidity(''); 
      } 
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Skapa konto</title>
   <link href="Stilmall.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
   <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/abel:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="reg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="form1">
    <form name="form2" id="form3" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="tack.html">

     <p class="form_text">
     <input type="text" id="epost" placeholder="E-post" required>
     <input type="text" id="repost" placeholder="Repetera E-post" required oninput="repost(this)">
     </p>

     <p class="form_text">
       <input type="submit" id="sumbit" value="Registrera">
     </p>
    </form>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: First, I would remove the character } that you have above your repost function

Comment: Use developer tools console to find errors in your code (press F12 in the browser)
in the snippet you posted you can easily see the error

Comment: will you include the entire external .js file?
also check the path that you have in the src for reg.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, this is a bit tricky but your id and function name both are "repost", in this situation you will get an error saying `repost is not a function` and you have to change the name of function or id. this has been discussed here : [Why JS function name conflicts with element ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id)

Also don't forget to fix the typo in your if condition.