# Cannot get button's onclick attribute to invoke JS function

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick

I have a simple form that, in jsfiddle I've simplified even further:

https://jsfiddle.net/mvw1nt5L/

Basically I have a table with just a header row.  Above it I have an "Add" button which each time it gets clicked is supposed to add a row to the table.

my button element is ...

```
<button id="addMeeting" type="button" onclick="addMeeting();" > Add A Meeting </button>
```

and the associated JS function is simply

```
function addMeeting() {
alert("add button clicked");
return false;
}
```

Real, real simple!   But it doesn't work.
the JS code is contained directly in the html document as a script tag.

What am I doing wrong?
TIA for any help!

Gus

Comment: not able to reproduce the error. Working fine for me

Comment: Gustaaf, there has to be a problem with the surrounding HTML. Is this an existing page? Its possible your event is being overwritten. Can I post a suggested edit that will help determine possible overwrite.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is set up so all the code is run onload. So it is not available on global scope. Your code looks like `window.onload = function () {  function addMeeting() {} }` Adjust the fiddle so it runs in the head or end of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a conflict between an element ID on your form and the function name. Or maybe not so much a conflict as a scoping issue. I've honestly never encountered this before until I tried to solve your problem. Very strange. Here's a more detailed explanation:

[Why JS function name conflicts with element ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id)

Comment: Spidy, this is interesting. I used addEventListener on Gustaafs fiddle and it fixes the issue tho.

Comment: Spidy,  thank you so much.  That was it.   When I changed the ID of the button element from "addMeeting" to "addMeetingButton", it started working.

Comment: @Bibberty That's because using addEventListener is executed from a different scope then the html onclick="". Just weird web things :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems it's a loading and scope issue. If you place a script tag before the html it will work just fine:

```html
<script>
function addMeeting() {
      alert("add button clicked");
      return false;
    }
</script>
    <button id="addMeeting" type="button" onclick="addMeeting()"> Add A Meeting </button>
```

alternatively you can also explicit use the window object:

```
window.addMeeting = function() {
      alert("add button clicked");
      return false;
    }
```

and:

```html
<button id="addMeeting5" type="button" onclick="window.addMeeting();"> Add A Meeting </button>
```