# Why form submit not working using function and submit input id same name?

Tags: javascript, html

i remove input submit id (id="signup") code is working properly but add id (id="signup") submit function not working
why ???

```js
function signup() {

  alert("form and return false is working");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return signup()">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="signup">
</form>
```

Comment: why do you think it isn't working with add id?

Comment: I think this will help with the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id

Comment: Use two different names for your function and your button. Like `id="signupButton"`.

Comment: @Gretch Richards : may be same function  name and same submit id , i'm testing this code multiple time .

Comment: `signup` function isn't working or submit isn't working?

Comment: Jeremy Thille : but i do not want use different function and button id . i already solved this code but no idea why not working  this code

Answer (score 0):

its very strange but maybe cause id is unique and in your code it's declared two times. one time for input and other time for function name.
try change function name or id name to something else then its work.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the function and the ID with the same string and that must be why your program is failing. Simply rename either the function or the id like so:

```js
function signup() {

  alert("form and return false is working");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return signup()">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitSignup">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but my question is why not working same id and function name

Comment: No problem I think @Lakshya provided a link to answer. Good day.