# Can access DOM elements outside HTML form but not inside. Not sure why

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm building a form where one of the fields gets the value of a stopwatch countdown. When stopped, the time elapsed should be submitted as part of the data. The stopwatch JS function works perfectly if rendered as an H1, but doesn't work when I try to render the same countdown as a form input value and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Specifically, it's the input value (incrementing digits) that does not render at all..it remains blank. A test function will work to alert "hello" as the `onclick`, but the desired function does not, though the same thing works outside the form. Here's my code:

```js
// Define vars to hold time vakues
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

// Define var to hold setinterval function
let interval = null;

// Define var to hold stopwatch status
let status = "stopped";

// Stopwatch logic to determine when to increment next value, etc.
function stopwatch() {
  seconds++;

  // logic to determine when to increment next value
  if (seconds / 60 === 1) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;

    if (minutes / 60 === 1) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  // If seconds/minutes/hours is only one digit, add a leading 0 to the values
  if (seconds < 10) {
    displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
  } else {
    displaySeconds = seconds.toString();
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
  } else {
    displayMinutes = minutes.toString();
  }

  if (hours < 10) {
    displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
  } else {
    displayHours = hours.toString();
  }

  // Display updated time values (increments in real time) to user
  document.getElementById("display").value = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
}

// Function to start / stop the watch
function startStop() {
  if (status === "stopped") {
    // Start the Stopwatch  (by calling the setInterval function)
    interval = window.setInterval(stopwatch, 1000);
    // Changes "start" button to "stop" button
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
    document.getElementById("startStop").style = "background: red";
    status = "started";

  } else {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
    status = "stopped";
  }
}


// Function to reset the Stopwatch
function reset() {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;

  document.getElementById("duration").value = "00:00:00";
  // Changes "stop" button to "start" button
  document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
}
```

```html
<form action="success.php" method="post">
  <label for="session-duration" class="form-label">duration: </label>
  <input type="text" name="session-duration" id="duration">
  <button type="button" name="button" id="startStop" onclick="startStop()">Start</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  <input type="submit" name="session-submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? You don't seem to update the "duration" element value at any point other than to reset it to 00:00:00.

Comment: Yes it is, the sequence starts by calling the stopwatch function within the startStop function:  if(status === "stopped"){
    // Start the Stopwatch  (by calling the setInterval function)
    interval = window.setInterval(stopwatch, 1000);

Comment: Actually I just figured out that accessing html element inside the form tags causes it to fail. Not sure why, but when I remove the form tags it works, so I will try to just keep the desired input as an H1 or something outside the form, access the value with JS and submit the value as a hidden input.

Comment: do you get error `Uncaught TypeError: startStop is not a function` ?

Comment: @Rap Sherlock, yes I do actually, which makes no sense, as the function is defined below. I have a paired down version of this that works, but without the styling, etc..but I can't figure out what is going wrong here. Here is a Pen with the simple version which minus some styling and elements is the same as what's not working - https://codepen.io/aguaclara/pen/Jjbwbro

Comment: Here's a pen with the failing version: https://codepen.io/aguaclara/pen/wvoRojm

Comment: i'm in mobile cant help you much but `Uncaught TypeError: startStop is not a function` is from `id="startStop" onclick="startStop()"` inside form id and function with same name will be causing conflict [here the detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/7058111)

Answer (score 0):

The current issue is that the `onclick` attribute, like other event attributes does pass the element on which the event occurred as the context, if you will, it's like calling the event handler with [`with( target ) {`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), so if you try to access a variable that is defined as a property of that element, it will get this instead of getting the one of the global scope (`window`).

```html
<button type="button" onclick="console.log(type)">log "button"</button>
```

Except that when in a `<form>` that form element gets used as the context. And since your element has its `id` set to `"stopWatch"`, the `stopWatch` property of that `<form>` element points to this `<button>`, and so does the bare `stopWatch` variable in the event handler.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("I'm not gonna be logged");
}
console.log( "from form", document.querySelector( "form" ).foo );
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" id="foo" onclick="console.log('from button\'s click', foo)">click me</button>
</form>
```

So when you click that button or the `id="reset"` one, it will try to call the element as a function, which fails.

The quick-fix is to change the ids of your elements so they don't override the function's name, and since [`HTMLFormElement.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) is a thing, you'd have to change that function's name too:

```js
// define vars to hold time vakues
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

// Define var to hold setinterval function
let interval = null;

// Define var to hold stopwatch status
let status = "stopped";

//stopwatch logic to determine when to increment next value, etc.
function stopwatch() {
  seconds++;

  // logic to determine when to increment next value
  if (seconds / 60 === 1) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;

    if (minutes / 60 === 1) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  // If seconds/minutes/hours is only one digit, add a leading 0 to the values
  if (seconds < 10) {
    displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
  } else {
    displaySeconds = seconds.toString();
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
  } else {
    displayMinutes = minutes.toString();
  }

  if (hours < 10) {
    displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
  } else {
    displayHours = hours.toString();
  }

  // Display updated time values to user
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
}

// Function to start / stop the watch
function startStop() {
  if (status === "stopped") {
    // Start the Stopwatch  (by calling the setInterval function)
    interval = window.setInterval(stopwatch, 1000);
    document.getElementById("startStop_").innerHTML = "Stop";
    document.getElementById("startStop_").style = "background:red";
    status = "started";

  } else {

    window.clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById("startStop_").innerHTML = "Start";
    document.getElementById("startStop_").style = "background:green";
    let time = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
//    document.getElementById("time-hidden").value = time;
    status = "stopped";
  }
}


// Function to reset the Stopwatch
function resetCounter() {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;

  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
  document.getElementById("startStop_").innerHTML = "Start";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container" style="width: 60%;">
  <div class="jumbotron text-left" style="padding: 10px 0px 20px; height: 400px;">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 20px; color: blue;">
      <?php echo $row['clinic_name']. " / " . $row['hours'] . "  hrs "; ?>
    </h4>
    <form class="" action="tr_create_session_success.php" method="post">
      <label for="session-date" class="form-label" style="display: inline; color: blue; margin-left: 20px; font-weight: lighter; ">date: </label>
      <input type="date" name="session-date" class="form-control" style="width: 23%; display: inline; margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <label for="session-duration" class="form-label" style="display: inline; color: blue; margin-left: 20px; font-weight: lighter; ">duration: </label>

      <span id="display" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">00:00:00</span>
      <button type="button" name="button" id="startStop_" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="startStop()" style="margin: 0 0 5px 3px">Start</button>
      <button type="button" name="button" id="reset_" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" onclick="resetCounter()" style="margin: 0 0 5px 3px">Reset</button>

      <textarea name="session-notes" rows="8" cols="130" class="new-status" placeholder="notes..."></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="tr-session-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="SUBMIT" style="margin: 0px 2% 0px 5px">
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

**But a better fix would be to not use `onevent` attributes, ever.**

Comment: Thank you!! I changed the element id to something else and it worked! Would have never thought this was creating a conflict since in another context/version the same naming was working. Thanks again.

Comment: @Argut https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

Here is a better `StopWatch`:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/etxternal.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, hmsd, StopWatch; // for reuse on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(node, ...classNames){
  node.classList.add(...classNames);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(node, ...classNames){
  node.classList.remove(...classNames);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(node, className){
  node.classList.toggle(className);
  return tC;
}
hmsd = (milliseconds, returnString = null)=>{
  let t = milliseconds, hf = 3600000, mf = 60000, sf = 1000, h = Math.floor(t/hf);
  let hm = h*hf, m = Math.floor((t-hm)/mf), mm = m*mf+hm, s = Math.floor((t-mm)/sf);
  let d = t-(s*sf+mm);
  if(h < 10)h = '0'+h;
  if(m < 10)m = '0'+m;
  if(s < 10)s = '0'+s;
  if(d < 10){
    d = '00'+d;
  }
  else if(d < 100){
    d = '0'+d;
  }
  if(returnString === true){
    h = ''+h; m = ''+m; s = ''+s; d = ''+d;
  }
  else if(returnString === false){
    h = +h; m = +m; s = +s; d = +d;
  }
  return {h:h, m:m, s:s, d:d}
}
StopWatch = function(watchNode, milliseconds = true, interval = 0){
  this.watchNode = watchNode; this.milliseconds = milliseconds; 
  this.interval = interval;
  let m = 0, now = 0, it;
  const fun = ()=>{
    const o = hmsd((now ? Date.now()-now : 0));
    this.current = watchNode.textContent = o.h+':'+o.m+':'+o.s+(this.milliseconds ? '.'+o.d : '');
  }
  this.start = ()=>{
    if(!it){
      now = now+Date.now()-m; it = setInterval(fun, this.interval);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.stop = ()=>{
    if(it){
      clearInterval(it); it = undefined; m = Date.now();
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.reset = ()=>{
    this.stop(); now = m = 0;
    this.current = watchNode.textContent = this.milliseconds ? '00:00:00.000' : '00:00:00';
    return this;
  }
  this.reset();
}
// tiny Library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load event *(except line with // end load)*
const stopWatch = new StopWatch(I('watch')), start_stop = I('start_stop');
const reset = I('reset');
let go = false;
start_stop.onclick = function(){
  if(go){
    stopWatch.stop(); rC(this, 'stop'); this.textContent = 'START';
  }
  else{
    stopWatch.start(); aC(this, 'stop'); this.textContent = 'STOP';
  }
  go = !go;
}
reset.onclick = ()=>{
  go = false; stopWatch.reset(); rC(start_stop, 'stop'); start_stop.textContent = 'START';
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{ /* set font deeper or white space may occur */
  box-sizing:border-box; font:0; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body,.full{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#wrapper,#stop_watch,#stop_watch>*{
  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#stop_watch{
  width:334px; background:#333; padding:10px; border:4px double #fff; border-radius:5px;
}
#watch{
  width:314px; background:#000; color:white; font:bold 40px monospace; margin-bottom:10px;
}
#stop_watch>button{
  font:bold 22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
button{
  cursor:pointer; background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff; border:1px solid #007; 
  font:bold 28px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:5px 15px; border:1px solid #007;
  border-radius:10px;
}
#start_stop{
  background:linear-gradient(#679467,#235023); border:1px solid #070; margin-right:7px;
}
#start_stop.stop{
  background:linear-gradient(#ad2323,#721818); border:1px solid #700; margin-right:8px;
}
#start_stop,#reset{
  width:calc(50% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='full' id='wrapper'>
    <div id='stop_watch'>
     <div id='watch'></div>
     <button id='start_stop'>START</button><button id='reset'>RESET</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
</html>
```

Too busy to explain, but though I'd throw it in, in case it helps. Hope I got the hours right. Didn't let it run that far, but should work.

Comment: Thank you for this stopwatch. I ended up using it as I keep getting errors with the other code. This works perfectly, thanks again.