# I try to make a On and Off button in html and but when I put the tag input inside the Form doesn't work it stay on off doesn't switch to On

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make a On and Off button in html and but when I put the tag input inside the Form doesn't work it stay on off doesn't switch to On

```js
function onoff() {
  currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
  if (currentvalue === "Off") {
    document.getElementById("onoff").value = "On";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("onoff").value = "Off";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="button" value="Off" id="onoff" onclick="onoff();" class="button button2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="button" value="Off" id="onoff" onclick="document.getElementById('onoff').value==='Off'?document.getElementById('onoff').value='On':document.getElementById('onoff').value='Off';" class="button button2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just rename your function name to not match `id` of the clicked target and your code will work:

### ```js
function onoffHandler() {
    currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
    if (currentvalue === "Off") {
        document.getElementById("onoff").value = "On";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("onoff").value = "Off";
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="button" value="Off" id="onoff" onclick="onoffHandler();" class="button button2">
</form>
```

This happens because a legacy scope being injected into the scope chain. But only for [inline handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). That allows to address **all** your forms' elements having `id` or `name` attribute by the same variable names. And since those `id` and `name` variables are in higher (closer) scope they shadow **all** other functions or variables with the same names.

If you need more thorough explanation what exactly is happening you may check out this [answer]
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160009/3388225).