# TypeError: login is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM188 index.html:76) onclick @ VM188 index.html:76

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a login page for my project I am working on and I came across this error while trying to run the code. I have no idea what is causing it.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JAuth Login</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.8.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/login.css">
</head>
<body>

  
  <script>
    //firebase stuff

    //Login

    //Authentication
    //login
    function login() {
       var userEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
       var userPass = document.getElementById("password").value;

       window.alert(userEmail + " " + userPass);
    }
  </script>

  <main class="d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100 py-3 py-md-0">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card login-card">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="assets/images/login.jpg" alt="login" class="login-card-img">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="brand-wrapper">
                <img src="assets/images/Jauth.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
              </div>
              <p class="login-card-description">Sign into your account</p>
              <form action="#!">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mb-4">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="***********">
                  </div>
                  <input name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-block login-btn mb-4" type="button" value="Login" onclick="login()">
                  <input name="register" id="register" class="btn btn-block login-btn mb-4" type="button" value="Register">
                </form>
                <a href="#!" class="forgot-password-link">Forgot password?</a>
                <nav class="login-card-footer-nav">
                  <a href="#!">Terms of use.</a>
                  <a href="#!">Privacy policy</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That was the full script.

When I run the code and go to chrome, I keep finding an error saying: `TypeError: login is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM188 index.html:76) onclick @ VM188 index.html:76`

Do you know what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: There are no `email` and `password` fields?

Comment: There are but I didn't add it in the code snippet do you need it?

Comment: It would be helpful if the snippet could reproduce the error you are having. There is currently no reason for `login` not to exist. We don't explicitly need those input fields, but we do need a [mcve].

Comment: The error the code snippet gives seems to be different from the error you give in the title. Additionally as Ivar says, you don't have "email" and "password" fields.

Comment: That is the error I got in the console though

Comment: I edited the snippet...

Comment: It works on stack overflow but not on the website

Comment: Then there must be something else going wrong on your website, because if your website were identical to this, it would work.

Comment: @JerryLin For the error you are getting it shouldn't. That error usually means that the function isn't declared in the right scope, or not at all (due to it not being loaded in or otherwise). But without a way for us to reproduce the problem, we can't really give you a definitive answer.

Comment: I would add the full code (the entire file)

Comment: There is a conflict in the name/id of your login field and the login function. Your `login` in `onclick="login()"` is referring to the HTML element, not to the function. If you use a different (unique) function name or (preferably) use `.addEventListener()`, it should work. (For add `.addEventListener()`, you _do_ need to move the script to the bottom of the page (under the last <script ...>`).) Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id

Comment: @Ivar I tried changing the function name to `UserLogin()` and changed the onclick event to `onclick="UserLogin"` and it showed the same error but instead the UserFunction function is not defined.

Comment: @Ivar, ok I would move the script to the bottom of the page

Comment: @Ivar It doesn't work

Comment: Try it [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/nd3tLzv0/) @JerryLin.

Comment: @Ivar I tried the listener but it doesn't change anything. I tried removing the onclick event but then the button doesn't do anything...

Comment: It does look like I have other javascripts attached, does that coflict whit anything?

Comment: My bad. The `onclick="login()"` should indeed be removed if you are using `.addEventListener()` instead. Removing the `onclick="login()"` should get rid of the error. If you get another error, make sure that the you select the right button (given that you changed the name). Other JS files _can_ conflict yes, but without seeing it, that is impossible to say.

Comment: I did get another error saying `Cannot use import statement outside a module` (Probably because of my firebase config) and the button still doesn't work. Can that error affect the button? Did it freeze the js code?

Comment: @Ivar no error regarding the button showed up but the button just didn't respond

Comment: I re-coded the entire thing and it seems to work better. The errors are gone but I am still dealing with other ones that I think I can resolve.